# How to increase precision of std::sin function on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, precision

I have a cross-platform application, which is an audio application and therefore uses sine waves a lot, and the `std::sin()` and other goniometric functions.

I noticed that particularly on the iOS platform, the precision of the `std::sin()` is extremely poor. I wrote the following test:

```
void TestSineZeroCrossings()
{
   const static float kTwoPi = 6.28318530718f;
   const static float epsilon = 1e-5f;

   for (int ii = 0; ii < 10000; ++ii)
   {
       const float difference = std::abs(std::sin(kTwoPi * static_cast<float>(ii)));
       if (difference >  epsilon)
          printf("Zero crossing fail, difference: %f\n", difference);
   }
}
```

On Windows and MaxOSX this passes (i.e. no print-outs), but on iOS this fails on pretty much every iteration. In fact, only with an `epsilon > 0.004f` does it succeed. That results in clearly audible noise in my application.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to use a better implementation that's not as lossy?

Comment: could be a CPU issue? x86 processors use 80-bit floats, a quick google indicates ARM's are only 64bit?

Comment: see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath for GCC options, most of which are probably available on clang

Comment: On a side note, the "normal" way to write `10e-6` is `1e-5`.

Comment: @SidS -- engineering notation sometimes uses powers of 10 that are multiples of 3. That way they line up with the corresponding prefixes kilo-, mega-, milli-, micro-, etc.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I see how that can be useful.  I'm finding out that what I was referring to is what's called ["normalized notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Normalized_notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the implementation is quite accurate.

Your actual problem is that `kTwoPi * static_cast<float>(ii)` gets rounded to the next `float`. E.g., for `ii=10000` the value is (if I did not miscalculate): `62831.8515625`
If you subtract `10000*2*pi` in exact math from that you get approximately: `-0.001509...` And the sine of that value is approximately the same (and not `0`). It is "relatively" close to zero but far away from your desired `10e-6` "accuracy".

If you want to have more accurate values for `sin(x*pi)`, have a look at `boost::math::sin_pi`:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/powers/sin_pi.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want more precision, use `double` or `long double` rather than `float`.

For instance,

replace

```
   const static float kTwoPi = 6.28318530718f;
   const static float epsilon = 10e-6f;
```

with

```
   const static double kTwoPi = 6.28318530718;
   const static double epsilon = 10e-6;
```

and

```
const float difference = std::abs(std::sin(kTwoPi * static_cast<float>(ii)));
```

with

```
const double difference = std::abs(std::sin(kTwoPi * ii));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is not about the fact that double precision is of course more precise than floating point, but about the fact that on some CPUs (i.e. my Windows one) this is performing differently compared to my iOS one.

Comment: It's not necessarily based on CPU.  I compiled your code for Win32, and running it on 64-bit Windows 10 resulted in the similar problems to those you mention on iOS.  The reason your code seems to work when you run it on Windows is more than likely that when you compile for 64-bit `float` and `double` are the same.  So by using `double` instead of `float` you get no extra cost on the platform where your code worked, but it does solve the problem for those platforms where it *didn't* work.

Comment: So by using `double` instead of `float` you get no extra cost on the platforms where your code worked, but it does solve the problem for those platforms where it *didn't* work.  I think you should reconsider who gave you the best answer here.

Comment: Yes, when using x87-math (which is/was the default on x86-32bit), all floating point variables are usually calculated with extended precision (i.e., 64bit mantissa), at least as long as they are on the FPU-stack. On x86-64bit, all floating point operations (by default) use the SSE registers, thus single precision floats actually get rounded to a 23bit mantissa. If (what the question suggests) the actual goal is to calculate `sin(x*twopi)`, the trick is to reduce `x` to the `[-0.5,0.5]` range before calculating the end result (which is what `sin_pi` essentially does).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of repetition, your problem is obviously the use of float rather than double or long double.

You could verify this by doing

```
cout << kTwoPi << endl ;
```

and seeing how many digits get printed out and how they compare to your original value.

> const static float kTwoPi = 6.28318530718f;

is roughly equivalent to

```
const static float kTwoPi = 6.283185 ;
```

on many (most?) systems.Your delta is way too small for a single precision value. Float is useless for most applications because of its usual lack of precision.

Comment: "Float is useless for most applications [...]" is a rather bold statement. Of course, one needs to pay more attention to avoid rounding problems, but in many cases using `double` only hides problems of using badly conditioned algorithms. When using SIMD, you get twice the throughput with single vs double precision. On most GPUs the gain is even higher (and some older GPUs don't even support double-precision math).